# How to get week start date of particular date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

'10/10/2018' is the given date, I want to find week start date in which this date falls..according to calendar

Comment: Start of the week depends on the culture. also is this field a date derivative, also you tagged C# what role does C# play in this, also you have shown no code, no research, and no problem as such

Comment: i just want to find start date of a week

Comment: it gives wrong date for 11/11/2018 @Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first day of the week like following.

```
 declare @inputdate date='10/10/2018'
 select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @inputdate)-1), @inputdate) [WeekStart]
```

If you want to change the first day of week to a specific day, for this you can use `SET DATEFIRST`

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
declare @inputdate date='10/10/2018'
select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @inputdate)-1), @inputdate) [WeekStart]
```

[**SET DATEFIRST**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, '10/10/2018)-1), '10/10/2018)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '10/10/2018' ), CAST('10/10/2018' AS DATE)) [Week_Start_Date]
```

Comment: it gives wrong date for 11/11/2018